# Why is GitHub Actions not picking up all the scripts in my test folder?

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions

I am using pytest in conjunction with GitHub Actions to run my unit test before pushing to the main branch.

However, pytest is only running the first script in my test folder where I have three different test scripts.

Here is my folder structure with three scripts in the `tests` folder:

```
guerrilla_forecast/
├─utils/
│ ├─__init__.py
│ ├─datapull.py
│ ├─google_bucket.py
│ ├─monthly_data_aggregation.py
│ ├─one_month_promotions.txt
│ ├─.ipynb_checkpoints/
│ │ ├─monthly_data_aggregation-checkpoint.py
│ │ ├─one_month_promotions-checkpoint.txt
│ │ ├─google_bucket-checkpoint.py
│ │ ├─datapull-checkpoint.py
│ │ ├─key1-checkpoint.json
│ │ └─prophet_daily-checkpoint.py
│ └─prophet_daily.py
├─requirements.txt
├─.github/
│ └─workflows/
│   ├─overview.md
│   └─python-app.yml
├─tests/
│ ├─forecast_test.py
│ ├─__init__.py
│ ├─daily_data_test.py
│ ├─monthly_aggregation_test.py
│ ├─.ipynb_checkpoints/
│ │ ├─daily_data_test-checkpoint.py
│ │ ├─forecast_test-checkpoint.py
│ │ ├─monthly_aggregation_test-checkpoint.py
│ │ └─__init__-checkpoint.py
│ └─.pytest_cache/
│   ├─v/
│   │ └─cache/
│   │   ├─stepwise
│   │   ├─lastfailed
│   │   └─nodeids
│   ├─README.md
│   ├─CACHEDIR.TAG
│   └─.gitignore
├─README.md
├─ssh.txt
├─pic_files/
│ └─seg.png
├─Dockerfile
└─.ipynb_checkpoints/
  ├─ssh-checkpoint.txt
  ├─requirements-checkpoint.txt
  ├─README-checkpoint.md
  └─Untitled-checkpoint.ipynb
```

Here is my workflow file running the action:

```yaml
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python 3.10
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: "3.10"
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pytest
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out.  I put all of my test scripts under one class.  Now the `Github` actions are picking them up.